# json_normalize with jsonArray data

Tags: python-3.x

I am dealing with JSON array data collected from a keyboard listener but, the challenge is I would love to normalize it so that I can feed it machine learning algorithms.

```
sampleData = ['{"event_type": "down", "scan_code": 35, "name": "h", "time": 1565259203.8081546, "is_keypad": false}', '{"event_type": "down", "scan_code": 30, "name": "a", "time": 1565259203.8479707, "is_keypad": false}', '{"event_type": "down", "scan_code": 31, "name": "s", "time": 1565259203.8499615 ]
```

and when i run the method below i get the output below.

```
[  event_type  scan_code name          time  is_keypad
0       down         35    h  1.565259e+09      False,   event_type  scan_code name          time  is_keypad
0       down         30    a  1.565259e+09      False,   event_type  scan_code name          time  is_keypad
0       down         31    s  1.565259e+09      False,   event_type  scan_code name          time  is_keypad
]
```

enter code here

```
def loadData(data):
     newdata = []
     for i in data:
          obj = json.loads(i)
          newdata.append(json_normalize(obj))
     return newdata
```

but i would love this output.

```
  event_type scan_code name time is_keypad
0  down        33       s    3456.0  False
1  up          1        x    445.9   False
```

Comment: Please provide more clear sample of your input data and expected output.

Comment: Sample data is like this ['{"event_type": "down", "scan_code": 35, "name": "h", "time": 1565259203.8081546, "is_keypad": false}', '{"event_type": "down", "scan_code": 30, "name": "a", "time": 1565259203.8479707, "is_keypad": false}', '{"event_type": "down", "scan_code": 31, "name": "s", "time": 1565259203.8499615, ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic was to first convert all the string dicts in sample data to dict and append them in an array. Then pass the array to the json_normalize function and all is done.